# Error after firebase authentication using facebook

Tags: ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate user using facebook through firebase:
[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrZob.png)

but getting [object Object] error:
[Loginfailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVUUx.png)

My code for login is:

```
facebookLogin(): void {
    this.fb.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
        const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
          .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
         .then((success) => {
            alert("Firebase success: ");
            this.userProfile = success;
         })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        });
    }).catch((error) => {alert(error); });
}
```

Comment: Change alert to view error `alert(JSON.stringify(error));`

Comment: After using `alert(JSON.stringify(error));` error that pops up is `{"errorMessage":"Facebook error: "}`

Comment: Are you following a guide? If yes, can you link it?

Comment: This is the link i followed as a guide https://javebratt.com/ionic-2-facebook-login/

Comment: not sure if it's a typo in your question but: the guide says to use `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);` and you forgot the `.` to link the `credential(..)` to `FacebookAuthProvider`

Comment: Alright, saw that the guy who edited this removed your `.`, re-edited your question

Comment: Please help me its really necessary for my project.

Answer (score 0):

All of the documentation I see requests both the email and the public_profile in the login function, perhaps this is the error.

```
this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then( (response) => {
```